# Multivariable irreducible polynomials over finite fields

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

It is not difficult to prove the following result, and it seems that it should be already proved. I would appreciate it if someone offer me some reference to it.

For any $f(x_1,\dots, x_n)=\sum c_{i_1\dots i_n} x_1^{i_1}\dots x_n^{i_n}\in \mathbb{F}_{q^N}[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ with integer $N\ge 1$ and any integer $j$, we define $f^{(q^j)}(x_1,\dots, x_n)=\sum c^{q^j}_{i_1\dots i_n} x_1^{i_1}\dots x_n^{i_n}$.

**Result:** Let $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $M$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $N$ be an arbitrary positive integer. Assume that $f_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ is a monic irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_{q^N}$ satisfying that $f_1\mid f$. Then there exists $l$ dividing $M$, such that $\mathbb{F}_{q^{M/l}}$ is the smallest field containing the coefficients of $f_1$, and
$$f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=c\prod_{j=0}^{M/l-1}f_1^{(q^j)}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n),$$
for some $c \in \mathbb{F}_q\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Since the result is well-known and trivial, I think it isn't an interesting question to ask for a reference: the first person to prove this was certainly whoever first considered the problem.  If you include this in a paper, I don't see how a reader would benefit by being told a citation to some previous paper which contains the one-line proof -- instead the reader would benefit more by just being told the one-line proof in your paper.

Comment: With that being said, did you look in standard coding theory books like Berlekamp's, for instance?  This is the sort of thing that might occur there (although it also was surely used by Carlitz many times, and perhaps by Dickson before him).

Comment: Just another reference: This result was also proved and used by R. Gow and J. Sheekey in their paper--On primitive elements in finite semifields in FFA 17 (2011)